# Pygame "Keep Going" IF statement

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to coding and pygame and I am trying to create a simple game. I am struggling a bit with this:

```
if player.collidrect(enemy): #If player collides with enemy
    if screen.blit(image1, (110, 0)): #check if this image is on the screen
        screen.blit(image2, (110, 0)) #If it is, put this image on top
```

(p.s dont worry about defining the stuff, my question doesn't have anything to do with that)

What I would like to happen is when the player collides with the enemy, check if 'image1' is on the screen and if it is, put 'image2' on the screen. The problem is, it displays 'image2' but ONLY while the player is colliding with the enemy. Once the player stops colliding, the image goes away. But want it to stay there. If you understand, can you help me find the command for making the 'image2' stay there even when the player stops colliding with the enemy? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`screen.blit(image1, (110, 0))` does not return if the image is on the screen or not, it returns the rect of where the image is on the screen, for example, if `image1` is 100x100, it will return (110, 0, 100, 100). You will need to find another way to see if the image is on the screen, maybe have a boolean and set it to True when you put the image on screen

```py
show_image1 = True
show_image2 = False

if show_image1:
    screen.blit(image1, (110, 0))
if show_image2:
    screen.blit(image2, (110, 0))

if player.collidrect(enemy): #If player collides with enemy
    if show_image1: #check if this image is on the screen
        show_image2 = True #If it is, put this image on top
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `screen.blit` doesn't return if it's on the screen. Second of all, this is what you want.

Try this:

```
if player.collidrect(enemy): #If player collides with enemy
    if <ON_SCREEN>
        show_image = True
```

Now when you render everything, do:

```
if show_image:
    screen.blit(image2, (110, 0))
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure to set `show_image` to `False` at the start of your game.